# Отделение интерфейса от базы, архетиктура объекта и методов

Tags: c, gtk, glib

Вопросы:
Организация структуры объекта? Организация сетеров и гетеров? 
Вопрос в том какая структура должна быть у объекта, не слишком ли я усложняю делая вложенные структур? Как его заполнять данными, все поля сразу, или на каждое поле свой сеттер и геттер. Я приложил свой код, меня смущает, что наполняется не весь объект сразу, за много вызовов методов, с другой стороны метод имеет не много аргументов.

Объект Connector

```
#ifndef _MYSQL_CONNECTOR_H
#define _MYSQL_CONNECTOR_H

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <mysql.h>

typedef struct _MYSQLConnector MYSQLConnector;

struct _MYSQLConnector
{
    void *priv;

    // Методы

    // Подключение к БД
    gboolean (*connect_db)(MYSQLConnector*);

    void (*destroy)(MYSQLConnector*);

    // Получение указателя на ДБ
    MYSQL *(*get_connect)(MYSQLConnector*);

    // Ошибки
    gchar *(*get_error)(MYSQLConnector*);
};
```

Объект User

```
#ifndef _MYSQL_USER_H
#define _MYSQL_USER_H

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql_connector.h"


typedef struct _MYSQLUser MYSQLUser

struct _MYSQLUser
{
    void *priv;

    // Методы
    void (*destroy)(MYSQLUser*);

    gchar *(*get_fname)(MYSQLUser*);
    gchar *(*get_lname)(MYSQLUser*);
    void (*set_fname)(MYSQLUser*,gchar *fname);
    void (*set_lname)(MYSQLUser*,gchar *lname);

    // Получение connector
    Connector *(*get_connector)(MYSQLUser*);

    // Запросы к БД 
    // Соединение с базой проверяется и устанавливается внутри запроса
    gboolean (*select_user)(MYSQLUser*, GSourceFunc function, gpointer user_data);
    gboolean (*insert_user)(MYSQLUser*, GSourceFunc function, gpointer user_data);
    gboolean (*update_user)(MYSQLUser*, GSourceFunc function, gpointer user_data);
    gboolean (*delete_user)(MYSQLUser*, GSourceFunc function, gpointer user_data);
};

// Методы
MYSQLUser *user_new(MYSQLConnector*);

#endif
```

Comment: Простите, но ваш вопрос напоминает древний анекдот:- Петька, приборы!- 38!- Что- 38? 8-\ - А что - приборы?... В чем, собственно, **ваш вопрос**?

Comment: Вопрос в том какая структура должна быть у объекта как его заполнять данными, все поля сразу, или на каждое поле свой сеттер и геттер

Comment: Мое сугубо личное мнение такое. У вас сплошные структуры, т.е. их поля открыты, а значит, это просто агрегаты данных без необходимости в поддержке внутренней согласованности - по крайней мере, *вы* их так рассматриваете. Значит, вполне можно обращаться к каждому полю отдельно, без всяких геттеров/сеттеров. Если же объект имеет какие-то свои инварианты - да, например, владеет своими полями-строками, то тогда нужно делать классы, инкапсулируя представление данных и работая через методы.

Comment: Я и пытаюсь написать класс, и обращаться к полям структуры при помощи методов которые ее создают, удаляют, наполняют

Comment: С точки зрения парадигмы GTK+  корректно объявленые структуры и функции инициализации. Что Вас не устраивает ?

Comment: Думаю объявленные структуры действительно надо сделать приватными и получать и наполнять их методами

Comment: typedef struct _MYSQLCatalog MYSQLCatalog;

struct _Object 
{
   MYSQLcatalog *priv;
};

Comment: @Алексей Это C здесь создание класса  и приватного элемента,это условность. Которую Вы реализуете самостоятельно.

Comment: @Yaroslav Да я понимаю что это условность

Comment: Нашел еще одно решение, не понимаю как выложить код, в комментарии нарушается форматирование, или редактировать сообщение? Хотел бы обсудить его

Comment: @Алексей редактируйте сообщение

Comment: OK сейчас выложу

Comment: Создаю объект "connector", затем создается объект "user" на вход передается указатель на "connector", таким образом объект "user" сможет подключатся к БД и получать ошибки, по аналогии объекта "user", будут созданы другие объекты унаследовавшие объект "connector"

Comment: @Алексей Это что за оформление ? Точно не С. Вызывать функции в обявлении структуре точно нельзя ))

Comment: Конечно это же  псевдокод

Comment: @Yaroslav Интересует именно архитектура, нужно расширяемость, код написать не проблема, надо выбрать именно архитектуру приложения и строго следовать ей, помогите выбрать.

Comment: @Yaroslav Склоняюсь к использованию объектной системы, внутри буду хранить методы. Плюсы: возможность наследования, переопределения методов, не загромождается пространство имен.

Comment: @Алексей использовать указатели на функции в структуре это очень хороший подход.

Comment: @Yaroslav Вчера не выдержал написал код, отладил, все работает,  сегодня проснулся смотрю на свой код и понимаю, что не так. Я сделал наследником "connector" ,  код получился не расширяемый.

Comment: @Yaroslav Устал переписывать одно и тоже, хочу определится с архитектурой и уже писать приложения

Answer (score 0):

Как Я понял. Вы хотите сделать систему в которой реализована возможность подключения к различным БД через одну структуру. И по возможности только добавлять драйвера для различных БД. Поэтому у Вас есть пользоватьель со стандартными параметрами подключения. Один из возможных вариантов.

```
enum
{
  TYPE_CONNECT_MYSQL = 0;
  AMOUNT_TYPE_CONNECT;
};   
typedef struct _connect_s connect_s;
typedef struct _user_s  user_s;    
struct  _connect_s;
{
  int flag;
  int (*init)(user_s * user);
  int (*open)(user_s * user);
  int (*close)(user_s * user);
};

struct _user_s
{
  char *db_host; 
  char *db_port;
  char *db_name;
  char *db_user;
  char *db_passwd;
  int type_connet; 
  connect_s connect;
};

int init_user(char * name ,int type_conect,<etc> )
{
 user_s * user = malloc(sizeof(user_s));
 switch(type_connect){
   case TYPE_CONNECT_MYSQL;
     user->connect.init = mysql_init;
     user->connect.open = mysql_open;
     user->connect.close = mysql_close;
 }
}
```

Comment: Я пытаюсь нащупать архитектуру моего приложения.

Comment: Если логика работы  программы предпологает у одного пользователя могут быть разные подключения , то структуру подключения лучше реализовать внутри структуры пользователя.

Comment: Алгоритм: Запустили программу, строится объект "Connector", собрали с формы данные, создаем объект "User" наполняем его данными, делаем запрос к базе, возвращаем результат запроса через callback функцию обратно, заполняем  интерфейс данными из объекта, разрушаем объект. Объект "Connector" остается и разрушается при закрытии программы. Когда мне нужно добавить товар, соответственно будет использован другой объект "Product" сщ своими методами, он также будет наследником объекта "Connector"

Comment: Тогда в каком направлении может быть рассширяемость. Увеличется колличество м\или качество БД или будет больше пользователей ? Сейчас одна БД один пользователь разные запросы.

Comment: Программу будет выполнять роль админки на сайте. Функционал, авторизация, работа с каталогом, работа с новостями, контакты и тд. пока не придумал, хочу изначально заложить в архитектуру программы расширяемость. Захотел добавить "Обзоры", создам объект интерфейса и объект для работы с БД, как то так.